# Make environment map scale when moving from the object

Tags: three.js, webgl

I use CubeCamera to build a simple reflection model. The setup can be seen on the picture below.

[image]

If the camera is close enough to the cube - the reflection looks fine. However, if  i move away from the objects - the reflection just gets bigger. See the picture below.

[image]

This is not the way i want it. I'd like the reflection to proportionally get smaller. I tried to play with different settings, then I thought this could be achieved using a proper shader program (just squish the cube texture, kind of), so i've tried to mess with the existing PhongShader, but no luck there, i'm too newbie to this.

Also, i've noticed that if i change the width and height of the `cubeCamera.renderTarget`, i.e.

```
cubeCamera.renderTarget.width = cubeCamera.renderTarget.height = 150;
```

i can get the proper dimensions of the reflection, but its position on the surface is wrong. It's visible from the angle presented on the picture below, but not visible if i place the camera straight. Looks like the texture needs to be centered.

[image]

[image]

The actual code is pretty straightforward:

```
var cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(1, 520, 512);

cubeCamera.position.set(0, 1, 0);
cubeCamera.renderTarget.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;
scene.add(cubeCamera);

var reflectorObj = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.CubeGeometry(20, 20, 20),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget,
        reflectivity: 0.3
    })
);

reflectorObj.position.set(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(reflectorObj);

var reflectionObj = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(5),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x00ff00
    })
);

reflectionObj.position.set(0, -5, 20);
scene.add(reflectionObj);

function animate () {
    reflectorObj.visible = false;
    cubeCamera.updateCubeMap(renderer, scene);
    reflectorObj.visible = true;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);  

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: The accepted answer is good, but ten years later there might be some ways around this problem. See [this](https://sbcode.net/threejs/reflector/) and [this](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#meshreflectormaterial) for things that could work for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment mapping in three.js is based on the assumption that the object being reflected is "infinitely" far away from the reflective surface.

The reflected ray used in the environment map look-up does not emanate from the surface of the reflective material, but from the `CubeCamera`'s center. This approximation is OK, as long as the reflected object is sufficiently far away. In your case it is not.

You can read more about this topic in this [tutorial](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_chapter07.html).

three.js r.58

Comment: Thanks for the link! It was useful.

Yes, i understand the underlying assumptions, but  aren't there any clever way to alter the default behaviour? For example, pass the cam position as a uniform into the shader and scale the texture accordingly to the distance between the object and the cam?

What are the techniques used to achieve the mirror-like reflection model then?

Comment: Within the framework of three.js, you can [Duplicate the geometry](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_text.html) or you can [Fool the Eye](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic2.html) and hope no one notices.

Comment: Ok, i see. Thanks for explanation! Will try to pick some techniques from this presentation http://29a.ch/slides/2012/webglwater/#title, looks like the author makes reflection on water with a shader. Will see how it goes.